# Aframe change object location with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am developing a game on A-frame.
In my game I need to make a shooting effect for which I am using a gun model and placing it behind the cursor, coded the click event so that an object will relocate in front of the gun and goes the direction of the cursor.

I am using `setAttribute` and requestAnimationFrame :-

```
renderObj: function(obj){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        renderObj(obj);
        });
    }
```

to create the animation effect of bullet moving in a particular direction.

when the function calls itself again I am not able to retrieve the location of the object set by setAttribute using

```
var objWorldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
objWorldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.object3D.matrixWorld);
```

whenever I change the position using setAttribute I am also updating the attribute in the bullet tag by `obj.attributes.position="x y z";` i know this is not the best practice as I should be able to recover the position so is there a way I can set the position of the element using three.js and the retrieve it using `THREE.Vector3()'s object3D.matrixWorld` method...

Any help will be appreciated thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't mix locating objects in three.js and a-frame, when setting the position in three.js via `object3D.position.set()`, i can't retrieve it via the `getAttribute('position')` method.
You can set the locataion by setting:

```
el.object3D.position.x = 5;
//OR
el.object3D.position.set(5,4,0);
//OR BY THE WORLD MATRIX AS 
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.set(11,12,13,14,
           21,22,23,24,
           31,32,33,34,
           41,42,43,44);
el.object3D.applyMatrix(matrix);
//RETRIEVE THE LOCATION:
console.log(el.object3D.position.x);
console.log(el.object3D.position);
console.log(el.object3D.matrixWorld);
```

As far as i know in this context the `Matrix4` is the [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). You can get information in explicit detail in the [three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Matrix4), and the [a-frame documentation](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/developing-with-threejs.md).

---

ngoKevin made something You are trying to achieve by:

1) Getting the gun position via the matrixWorld

```
var matrixWorld = gunEl.object3D.matrixWorld;
position.setFromMatrixPosition(matrixWorld);
bulletEl.setAttribute('position', position);
```

2) Setting the bullet rotation:

```
var rotation = gunEl.getAttribute('rotation');
bulletRotation = bulletEl.getComputedAttribute('rotation');
  bulletEl.setAttribute('rotation', {
    x: bulletRotation.x + rotation.x,
    y: bulletRotation.y + rotation.y,
    z: bulletRotation.z + rotation.z
  });
});
```

Then add the bullet via `appendChild()` and make it move on `tick()`

Check out the [project](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-fps-example), as it will definitely help You out.

Comment: thanks for the answer it helped me a lot... if anybody in future sees this the el.object3D.position works fine for any object but it wont give you the position of cursor if you are using it, yYu need to access its location using el.object3D.matrix.elements[12] as mentioned above 12 is for x, 13 is for y and 14 is for z.